# Is the "exercises" tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've been wondering if [exercises](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises) is necessary.  It and [practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) are not being used consistently, so if both stay around then they need to be more clearly defined.

As I see it, all exercises are practice.  All practice is **an** exercise.  However, not all practice is exercise in the sense of strengthening, building endurance, etc.

Is the third case enough to distinguish these tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) should refer to things *about* practicing. For example, the questions we have about [mental](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/322/133) [practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/387/133), or this one about ["deep practice"](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/438/133).

[exercises](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises) would not really apply to these. It's true that any exercises being done may indeed happen during practice time, but it's not *about* practicing, it *is* practicing. I see [exercises](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises) as referring to etudes, warmups, and routines.

Are there any questions in particular you feel are mistagged with these two?

Comment: Makes sense to me.  There was [one question for sure that I retagged](http://music.stackexchange.com/posts/2298/revisions), I didn't pay as much attention to the less-obviously-distinguishable ones. I'll go through them all once we have a consensus and update the tag wikis.